# I've been playing around with the strings method in Python and I was looking for some help in understanding the following behaviour:

Tags: python, string, split

If we considered this input in Python:

```
s="""David Smith 17,15,14,19
     Melina Jackson 15,16,17,19
     Charli Decker 14,15,18,15"""
```

If we considered this string in 3 lines, and each line separated with "Enter" and some space between them, how could we this output:

```
{
    "David_Smith": 16.25,
    "Melina_Jackson": 16.75,
    "Charli Decker": 15.50
}
```

I want the result to be the average of the input numbers.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. State clearly what you are trying to achieve and what you have tried so far.

Comment: How is the numbers calculated?

Comment: average of numbers  @CutePoison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer as you changed Question**

Code :

```py
s = """David Smith 17,15,14,19
Melina Jackson 15,16,17,19
Charli Decker 14,15,18,15"""

lines = s.split('\n')
mydict = {}


for detail in lines :

    newno = []
    items = detail.split(' ')
    nos = items[2].split(',')
    for s in nos :
        newno.append(int(s))    

    avg = float(sum(newno)/len(newno))
    name = str(items[0])+' '+str(items[1])
    mydict[name] = avg

print(mydict)
```

Output :

`{'David Smith': 16.25, 'Melina Jackson': 16.75, 'Charli Decker': 15.5}`

Comment: Nice. Thank you!

Comment: @SeyedAmirVahabi Welcome ! If my answer fulfills your question you can accept my answer by clicking the check mark.

Comment: we can complete it with these:

Comment: lines = s.strip().split("\n")

Comment: items = detail.strip().split(' ')

Comment: nos = items[2].strip().split(',')

Comment: @SeyedAmirVahabi Yes. Simpler way

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is :

1. Split the string every space. It will create a list with 3 elements per person : first name, last name and marks (I guess)
2. Iterate over the list. First we concatenate the first name and last name into `Mark_Twain`. Then we calculate the mean. Then we add this pair into a dictionary

```py
def calc_mean(numbers: list[int]) -> float:
    """calculate a mean"""
    return sum(numbers) / len(numbers)


def extract_mean_from_string(s: str) -> dict:

    arr = s.strip().split(" ")

    means = {}

    i = 0
    while i < len(arr):
        name = arr[i] + "_" + arr[i + 1]
        string_numbers = arr[i + 2]
        numbers = list(map(int, string_numbers.strip().split(",")))
        means[name] = calc_mean(numbers)

        i += 3
    return means


# If we considered this input in Python:
s = """David Smith 17,15,14,19 Melina Jackson 15,16,17,19,20 Charli Decker 14,15,18 """

# I want to have this output:
expected = {"David_Smith": 16.25, " Melina_Jackson": 21.75, "Charli Decker": 15.75}

print(expected)
print(extract_mean_from_string(s))
```

```
{'David_Smith': 16.25, ' Melina_Jackson': 21.75, 'Charli Decker': 15.75}
{'David_Smith': 16.25, 'Melina_Jackson': 17.4, 'Charli_Decker': 15.666666666666666}
```

Those are the correct values.

Comment: If we considered this string in 3 lines, and each line separated with "Enter" and some space between them, how could we solve it?

Comment: @SeyedAmirVahabi  Assuming that you said enter is newline `"David Smith 17,15,14,19\n"` we can split this into lines using `"\n"`

Comment: @SeyedAmirVahabi Check I posted answer due to your edit in the question